# Why my api routes are not working after i moved my angular app inside of my node.js server app?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have my `express(node.js)` app in which i moved my `angular(dist folder)` app inside my `express` in `public` folder.

Here i am setting my static content inside my `app.js(inside express app)`

```
const publicStatic = `${__dirname}/public/dist/`

app.use(express.static(publicStatic))
app.use((req, res) => { res.sendFile(publicStatic + 'index.html');
```

Now when i load my brwoser with this `http://localhost:5002/auth/login` so i see my `angular` app login page. But when i try to login by entering credentials and hitting login so my api is not responding and i am getting this error in console

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Here is my network call

[image]

Note: If i hit my any api endpoint with postman so it gives me `index.html` page from my angular's app dist folder inside my `express app`.

So how can i server my angular app with express app correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.use((req, res) => { res.sendFile(publicStatic + 'index.html');
```

This middleware always returns the `index.html`. I think you need to update it:

```js
const publicStatic = `${__dirname}/public/dist`

app.use(express.static(publicStatic))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.url.includes('/api')) {
      next();
  } else if (req.url.split('.').length > 1) {
      res.sendFile(publicStatic + req.path);
  } else {
      res.sendFile(publicStatic + '/index.html');      
  }
});
```

Comment: No my `angular` routes and api endpoints are different. see my updated post.

Comment: is this the proper way to do it or is there any better or best way to do it?

Comment: And your solution is not working. It's giving me my default message on browser which i have configured for invalid routes.

Comment: you can start to debug yourself by checking the `req.path` and `req.url`.